# Swiperjs slides wont slide properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ionic-framework, swiper.js

I am using swiperjs and I am having difficulty making the slides
as they wont snap to the next slide and I cant get the active index from them this is my code
where am I going wrong I am using typescript and swiperjs version 6.84 with the ionic framework

```
import 'swiper/components/navigation/navigation.min.css'
import 'swiper/components/pagination/pagination.min.css'






  const pagination = {
    clickable: true,
  };
 
  return (
    <IonPage>
  

      <Swiper
        pagination={pagination}
        
        onBeforeSlideChangeStart={e => {
          setIndex(e.activeIndex)
        }}>
        <SwiperSlide >
          <item property={property} index={0} save={dispatch} activeIndex={index} />
        </SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide >
            <item 2 property={property} index={1} />
        </SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide >
            <item3 property={property} index={1} />
        </SwiperSlide>
      </Swiper>
      <IonButton
        disabled={true}
        onClick={(e) => {
          e.preventDefault();
        }}
        className={"next"}
        expand={"block"}
      >
        Save
      </IonButton>
    </IonPage>
  );
}
```

Comment: what behavior are you seeing? see example here - https://codesandbox.io/s/reactjs-swiperjs-dynamic-slides-oesuw?file=/src/App.js

Comment: it doesnt react  when I move it I tried to add the observer and observer parents to true but it just makes my component slides in too one long slide that does work correctly what should I do ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to add ionContent so the slides were not reacting in the correct way I also had to add observe

```
 <IonPage>
  
<IonContent fullscreen>
      <Swiper
        pagination={pagination}
        observeParents={true}
        observer={true}
        onBeforeSlideChangeStart={e => {
          setIndex(e.activeIndex)
        }}>
        <SwiperSlide >
          <item property={property} index={0} save={dispatch} activeIndex={index} />
        </SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide >
            <item 2 property={property} index={1} />
        </SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide >
            <item3 property={property} index={1} />
        </SwiperSlide>
      </Swiper>
      <IonButton
        disabled={true}
        onClick={(e) => {
          e.preventDefault();
        }}
        className={"next"}
        expand={"block"}
      >
        Save
      </IonButton>
</IonContent>
    </IonPage>
```

Comment: you dont need any of that observer code... I would remove it so it isnt confusing to others who see this solution

Comment: I do I am using verison 6.84 my personal solution doesnt work with out it @AaronSaunders  but thank you for the clarity for others that may  have different code to me